# Program Continually Loops

Tags: c

I have created a program that asks for two numbers between 100 & 150. Also the difference between these numbers must be less than or equal to 10. I run the program but it doesn't end it continually loops even when I enter the correct values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE

int main(void)
{
  double a, b;
  double epsilon = 10.000000001;
  int flag_1, flag_2;

  flag_1 = FALSE;
  flag_2 = FALSE;
  do
  {
      printf("Enter in two values between 100.0 & 150.0\n");
      printf("The difference between each value must be less than or equal to 10.0\n\n");
      printf("Enter in value a: ");
      scanf("%lf", &a);
      printf("Enter in value b: ");
      scanf("%lf", &b);

      if (((a < 100.0)||(a > 150.0))||((b < 100.0)||(b > 150.0)))
      {
        printf("Error Enter between 100.0 & 150.0\n\n");
        flag_1 = TRUE;
      }
      else if (((a - b) > (epsilon))||(((a - b)*(-1)) > (epsilon))) 
      {
        printf("Error\n\n");
        flag_2 = TRUE;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Values a & b are: a = %lf, b = %lf\n\n", a, b);
      }
  }while((flag_1 == TRUE)||(flag_2 == TRUE));

  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try initialising a and b also

Comment: Try using `%f` in all the `printf`s. Also, try adding `flag_1 = FALSE; flag_2 = FALSE;` at the start of the `do...while` loop.

Comment: Reset the flags inside the loop, otherwise your condition will be false once it was false. In other words. Move `flag_1/2 == FALSE;` at inside the `do` loop before you check the validity of the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the values of `flag_1` and `flag_2` to `FALSE` right after

```
do {
```

Otherwise, their values from the previous iteration of the loop persist. Use:

```
do {
   flag_1 = flag_2 = FALSE;
```

Comment: I don't understand why when I enter correct values and no flag is set to TRUE it repeats. Although the program works now so thank you.

Comment: Because once either of those values is set to to `TRUE` they never get set back to `FALSE` in your code, so if either gets set just once, the loop will run forever.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset the flags to FALSE in the beginning of the while loop. Assume this case:
`a =180 and b =50.` The program will enter in the `if` case and `flag_1` is set to `TRUE`. Since it is `TRUE`, the loop will run again. Now, in this iteration, even if you enter right values of a and b, since the flag is `TRUE`, the program will keep running.